# How to copy first n rows in dataframe in spark?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Let's consider a following dataframe:

```
   name    3       43
   pol     1        89
   xaw     0         6
   qwe     12        569
```

How to duplicate first `k` rows?
I mean a following (example) output for `k=3`:

```
   name    3       43
   name    3       43
   pol     1        89
   pol     1        89
   xaw     0         6
   xaw     0         6
   qwe     12        569
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union` and `limit`:

```
var k = 3
df.union(df.limit(k)).show
+----+---+---+
| _c0|_c1|_c2|
+----+---+---+
|name|  3| 43|
| pol|  1| 89|
| xaw|  0|  6|
| qwe| 12|569|
|name|  3| 43|
| pol|  1| 89|
| xaw|  0|  6|
+----+---+---+
```

However the concept of first k rows is not well-defined because Spark dataframes are unordered.